# In Typescript and Angular 2+, How Do I Define a Variable of Custom Type from 3rd Party Library?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm-install

My setup involves Angular 4.1, Angular-CLI 1.1, Typescipt 2.3.2, and importing 3rd party apps with npm.

I installed the 3rd party fake app 'widget.js' via npm.
I want to call the Widget function defined below, which returns a class of WidgetMgr, and set that to a variable in `app.component.ts'.

QUESTION #1: How do I import the widget.js library? Goal is to be able to define a variable of type WidgetMgr. Is one of these better than the other, or are they both wrong?

```
import { Widget, WidgetMgr } from 'widgetjs';
import 'widgetjs';
```

QUESTION #2: How do I set `myWidgetMgr` to a custom type without throwing errors of type unknown? I know `any` will always work, but I'd like to learn the right way.

----  from app.component.ts

```
import // ??? QUESTION #1 - finish this statement

export class AppCompent {

private myWidgetMgr: any; // QUESTION #2 - replace 'any' with custom type

constructor() {
    this.myWidgetMgr = new Widget();

}

}
```

---  from /node-modules/widgetjs/widget.js

```
(function() {

...

    function Widget() {
        return new WidgetMgr(); // WidgetMgr is also defined in widget.js
    }

...

})();
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Comment: If you use IDE's like VSCode, you can use Extensions like Auto Import or Typescript Importer. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pmneo.tsimporter this will ease your pain

Comment: You'd replace any with Widget once you have your imports sorted. There is the Typescript As keyword that also sometimes comes in useful when converting result from interface to concrete class. eg getElementByID/querySelector - returns Element and you might want HTMLDivElement. so you'd have divElement:HTMLDivElement; as class property and do this.divElement = document.querySelector('#myDiv');